# options and setup before create a local repository

Tags: repository

I'm using 64 bits version of Precise Pangoling, I need to create a local repo but for the 64 bit of Quantal Quetzal, I think I have all the steps but I have some extra questions, I want to share them with you, suggestions are welcome:

1. I just want the packages for 64 bit arch, how and where can I set this?
2. I need to include virtualbox repo, is this package on the official repos? in case no, is there anyway to include it on my local repo?
3. my internet connection is not so fast as I would like, is there any "minimal or standard configuration" in order to not download the entire repos?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's go.

First of all to download the packages you need to make a local repo you have to use apt-mirror.

[Here](http://www.packtpub.com/article/create-local-ubuntu-repository-using-apt-mirror-apt-cacher) is a good start tutorial how to use apt-mirror.

Sure virtualbox package is not found in the main repo so in order to make it in your local repo just add the virtualbox repository to the mirror configuration files in the tutorial above...

This [link](http://www.itworld.com/software/304613/install-virtualbox-ubuntu-1210) may help you

Or easily you can just download the .deb file from [here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.2/virtualbox-4.3_4.3.2-90405~Ubuntu~quantal_amd64.deb) and add it to your local repo

Now for your internet connection there i am sorry to say that there is no solution for that, but you can do something to reduce the number of packages. you can reduce the number of the repos in the apt-mirror configuration file.